# C# Regex to get string between two strings with a wildcard string in between?

Tags: c#, html, regex, tags, wildcard

I know this has been asked in some capacity - but I was not able to see working example of the solution yet. I know that there is the [Html](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) Agility Pack to parse HTML strings, but I do not wish to download/install it. I get the contents of a webpage using

```
string html = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
```

I have a tags which have a class with them, but some of those tags also have their own ID, or style, etc for example:

```
<td>I Dont want this</td>
<td class="myClass">I want this</td>
<td class="myClass" id="myID">I want this</td>
<td style="border-top-width: 0px; class="myClass">I want this</td>
```

I tried

```
<td>(.*?)</td>
```

But it returns the tags without any class, id, etc.

I tried

```
<td class="myClass"[^>]*>(.*?)</td>
```

But it returns only the second and third `<td>` values but not the fourth. How can I add a wildcard to return any `<td>` with `myClass` but ignores anything that comes before or after like `id` or `style`?

Comment: I'm compelled to point you to [this rather famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: That part of HTML will ALWAYS have the same format as specified by the question. There will not be any errors or overloads that browsers autocomplete and autocorrect for.

Comment: Just add another `[^>]*` before the `class` attribute.  If your HTML is as consistent as you say, that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This will only identify if a `<td` has a class or id attribute.
It passes if either one has.

*If you require only a class value and id is optional, change the conditional

to `(?(class)|(?!))`*

After it finds the opening tag, this method just find's the very next closure.
(*Note that it doesn't check if the opening `<td` is a self contained tag.

If that's possible, add `(?<!/>)` right after the atomic group* i.e (?>..)`(?<!/>)`)

The class and id values are in their named capture groups.

Verbatim

`@"(?is)<td(?=\s)(?>(?:(?<=\s)class\s*=\s*""(?<class>[^""]*)""|(?<=\s)id\s*=\s*""(?<id>[^""]*)""|"".*?""|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>)(?(class)|(?(id)|(?!))).*?</td\s*>"`

Expanded

```
 (?is)
 < td                   # 'td' tag, or any tag for that matter
 (?= \s )
 (?>                    # Atomic grouping
      (?:
           (?<= \s )
           class  \s* = \s*       # 'class' attribute
           "
           (?<class>              # 'class' value                                                      
                [^"]*                  
           )
           "
        |  (?<= \s )
           id  \s* = \s*          # 'id' attribute
           "
           (?<id>                 # 'id' value                                                      
                [^"]*
           )
           "
        |  " .*? "
        |  ' .*? '
        |  [^>]*? 
      )+
      >
 )
 (?(class)              # Conditional - Only tags with our 'class' or 'id' attr/value
   |  
      (?(id)
        |  (?!)
      )
 )
 .*? 
 </td \s* >
```

---

Btw, on your last line `<td style="border-top-width: 0px; class="myClass">I want this</td>`
*style* value encloses the class= part
`style="border-top-width: 0px; class="`

Answer (score 0):

That should do it: `<td(.+|)(class="myClass")(.+|)>(.+)<\/td>`

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/gG6gH0/2

But if the list is any a different format then you described then you must exclude the '<' , '>' characters from the capturing group.